# MySQL Function is not compiled true

Tags: mysql

I tried to create this simple function, but I have the following error message;

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(customerLevel);
>   END' at line 17

here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION GetCustomerLevel(CustomerID INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE credit DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE customerLevel VARCHAR(20);
    SELECT SUM(total_price) 
    INTO credit
    FROM sales s,customer c
    WHERE c.customer_id= CustomerID And s.customer_id=c.customer_id ;

    IF credit > 1400 THEN
        SET customerLevel = 'PLATINUM';
    ELSE
        SET customerLevel = 'NOT PLATINUM';
    END IF;
    RETURN (customerLevel);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried to debug that error message?

Comment: delimiter ; (space between delimiter and delimiter value)

Answer (score 0):

I just shut down MySQL server and restart it and the code run without any error!
Thanks all :)